What is the relevant standard for an “86 type” [86mm] electrical box?

Note: I’m asking about EU and/or Chinese electrical standards, not about any particular device.

I was looking at listings for the Tuya 8-inch wall touchscreen, and the specifications describe it as fitting a “double 86” electrical box.

I don’t have a link for the Tuya 8-inch wall touchscreen because Tuya-powered products generally don’t have manufacturer product pages in English, and I didn’t think a link to a third-party reseller would be helpful.
Here’s a DuckDuckGo search, though.

Doing several quick web searches, the phrase “86 type” keeps popping up, and it seems to refer to an 86mm x 86mm electrical box.
I know the UK and the EU use square electrical box modules, but the UK apparently uses 70mm modules. I did see a number of products for the EU marketed as being 86mm, though.
What I was not able to find was where the code-based 86mm electrical box originates. I assume it’s from either the EU or from China, but I haven’t been able to find any relevant specifications.
I found my way here via this post as a search result, and while no one explains 86mm boxes there it gave me the thought to ask here.
So: what is the relevant standard for an “86 type” [86mm] electrical box?

What I’m hoping to find is something along the lines of a summary of e.g. an IEC standard.
(For comparison, I was able to find a reasonable approximation of a standard for a “UL2459 [luminaire disconnect] connector” a while back.)

Thanks!

If you’re in the US and that device isn’t UL listed, you’re taking on a certain amount of risk. You might try to confirm with the manufacturer…

Does this device necessarily need to run on AC mains power?  If it does, it and the boxes would need UL/CSA/ETL listing to be used in North America.  If the low voltage plugs into it (e.g. from an external power supply) then you're off the hook, but must use a UL listed power supply.

For the purposes of this question, imagine I am installing this Chinese product in either China or the EU. It don’t know if it’s up to code in China, but it’s made by one of the more prominent smart-home integration companies there (Tuya), so I imagine it probably is.

I should also clarify that I’m not asking about the Tuya product, per se, but rather the electrical standards in China and/or the EU, i.e.: what is a “type 86” electrical box? And which electrical code does it come from?
